# How to get the sum of the volume of highest and lowest priced items in linq

Tags: c#, linq

The actual query I am trying to write is slightly trickier than the title suggests. I have a list of orders like such: `List<Order>`, an order looks like this:

```
public class Order
{
    private StockCodes _stockCode;
    private bool _bidSide;
    private int _volume;
    private decimal _price;
}
```

I need to publish the best bid price and volume and the best sell price and volume given a specific stock code.  The best bid price is defined as the HIGHEST price where bidSide is true. The best sell price is defined as the LOWEST price where bidSide is false.

For example given the following data for stock code "ABC":

```
 { bidSide: true, volume: 25, price: 25  }
 { bidSide: true, volume: 25, price: 25  }
 { bidSide: true, volume: 25, price: 5  }

 { bidSide: false, volume: 100, price: 1  }
 { bidSide: false, volume: 50, price: 2}
 { bidSide: false, volume: 75, price: 8 }
```

Best bid: price 25, volume 50 (since there are 2 orders at the highest price)
Best sell: price 1, volume 100 (since there is just 1 order at the lowest price)

Lastly, I need to account for when there are no bid or sell orders.  Efficiency is of high priority, so If I am able to do this in one linq statement that would be preferred.

Comment: Is this LINQ to Objects?

Comment: (And can you separate the data into the different bid sides *once* before doing lots of processing? That would obviously be convenient...)

Comment: Any limits on the price? Always positive and always below (say) 1e20 would be handy :)

Comment: @Jon. Yes, this is Linq to Objects. As I mentioned it is List<Order>.  I would prefer not to separate the List into two.   The price is always positive and for the sake of this we'll say yes it is always below 1e20, though I am not sure how that matters.

Comment: Ah - the formatting wasn't helping there. Have edited to fix it. It matters because it makes it easier to account for "I haven't seen any orders of that type" yet, instead of needing an extra flag.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To do this efficiently, you really only want to iterate over the data once. Unfortunately, that makes it a real pain to implement with LINQ, as there's quite a lot of work to do.

Personally I would suggest that you *don't* do this with LINQ - you *could* implement it with `Aggregate`, but it wouldn't be terribly pleasant. It's not too bad with a simple `foreach` loop though. Something like:

```
int buyVolume = -1;
int sellVolume = -1;
decimal buyPrice = decimal.MinValue;
decimal sellPrice = decimal.MaxValue;

foreach (var order in orders)
{
    if (order.bidSide)
    {
        if (order.Price > buyPrice)
        {
            buyPrice = order.Price;
            buyVolume = order.Volume;
        }
        else if (order.Price == buyPrice)
        {
            buyVolume += order.Volume;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (order.Price < sellPrice)
        {
            sellPrice = order.Price;
            sellVolume = order.Volume;
        }
        else if (order.Price == sellPrice)
        {
            sellVolume += order.Volume;
        }
    }
}

// Check sellVolume == -1 to verify whether we've seen any sale orders
// Check buyVolume == -1 to verify whether we've seen any buy orders
// Use buyPrice/buyVolume and sellPrice/sellVolume otherwise
```

Doing it as efficiently as possible in LINQ would effectively mean putting *all* that logic in the loop into a function to pass into `Aggregate` - and you'd probably want to create a custom value type to hold the four values, to avoid creating more objects than you need to. That *may* be overkill, but you did say you wanted it as efficient as possible...

Answer (score 0):

```
HIGHEST = orders.Max(x => x.bidSide ? x.price : (decimal?)null) ?? 0M
```

Similar for LOWEST.

Linq2SQL will not convert this into an efficient query, unfortunately. It will execute in one single query, but the data will be scanned once per Max operation (in your case two times: HIGHEST and LOWEST). In raw SQL you can do this in one pass over the data.

Comment: I don't think this is quite right. I need the sum of the volume of all orders at the highest price as well as that price for bidSide == true. I also need the sum of the volume of all orders at the lowest price as well as that price for bidside == false.

Answer (score 0):

This could do LINQ wise...

```
var bids = (from o in orders
                where o.StockCode == "ABC" && o.BidSide == true
                group o by o.Price)
                .OrderByDescending(g => g.Key)
                .FirstOrDefault();
var bidVolume = bids != null ? new Order { Price = bids.Key, Volume = bids.Sum(g => g.Volume) } : null;

var sells = (from o in orders
                where o.StockCode == "ABC" && o.BidSide == false
                group o by o.Price)
                .OrderBy(g => g.Key)
                .FirstOrDefault();
var sellVolume = sells != null ? new Order { Price = sells.Key, Volume = sells.Sum(g => g.Volume) } : null;
```

Comment: Grouping and then sorting isn't going to be nearly as efficient as it *can* be.

Comment: @JonSkeet I do not question that - and if it's To Objects, I see that was brought up. You did that part perfectly, so nothing to add there, I though just to add another option. And I'm guessing it could be stop-watched to see exactly if it makes that big a difference in the particular case.

Comment: @JonSkeet Also - it'd make sense if e.g. you'd need to present a grid of symbols (with volumes, or 'Take' a first n) - in which case the more procedural algorithm would complicate (slightly though).

Comment: Sure - but I'm just going by what the question requires :)