# LINQ: Efficient way to get sum of all child items

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have the following for each loop to get sum of all child objects. Is there a better way using LINQ?

```
Purchase p1 = db.Purchases.FirstOrDefault(p => p.PurchaseId == 1);

int total = 0;
foreach (SellingItem item in p1.SellingItems)
{ 
   total = total + Convert.ToInt32(item.Price);
}
```

[image]

REFERENCE:

1. [How to get the sum of the volume of highest and lowest priced items in linq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10165396/how-to-get-the-sum-of-the-volume-of-highest-and-lowest-priced-items-in-linq)
2. [Using the ALL operator in linq to filter child items of EntitySet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3524466/using-the-all-operator-in-linq-to-filter-child-items-of-entityset)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Sounds like you just want:

```
// Any reason for FirstOrDefault rather than SingleOrDefault?
var purchase = db.Purchases.FirstOrDefault(p => p.PurchaseId == 1);

if (purchase != null)
{
    var total = purchase.SellingItems
                        .Sum(x => Convert.ToInt32(x.Price));
    ...
}
// TODO: Work out what to do if there aren't any such purchases
```

Why do you need the conversion of the price though? What type is `Price`, and why isn't it already the right type? (And does that really want to be `int` rather than `decimal`?)

Comment: I am using FirstOrDefault to ensure that I will not get exception even if there are multiple items. Will the use of SingleOrDefault increase performance?

Comment: @Lijo: Quite possibly not - but wouldn't the presence of multiple items with the same ID indicate a serious data problem, suggesting it's better to bail than continue in uncharted territory?

Answer (score 3):

```
p1.SellingItems.Sum(p => p.Price)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using the Linq [Sum](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534734.aspx) method:

```
Purchase p1 = db.Purchases.FirstOrDefault(p => p.PurchaseId == 1);

int total = p1.SellingItems.Sum(item => Convert.ToInt32(item.Price));
```

It is not more efficient, in that it will not be any faster. But it is more concise.

Comment: It may be faster, if this is done in the database... no need to pull data back just for summing.

Comment: @JonSkeet good point. I've only ever used Linq-to-Objects, rather than Linq-to-SQL